# head.js "Modernizr" like feature doesn't detect ms-edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-agent, head.js

I've noticed that `head.js` doesn't detect Microsoft "Edge" browser, and to top that, it adds incorrect `chrome` and `chrome55` classes to the `<html>` element.

Does anyone know of a suitable way to approach this issue? The best approach I could come up with is to perform this check in my app's bootstrap - manually detect "Edge" browser, add appropriate "ms-edge" class, and remove head.js incorrect "chrome" classes:

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') > -1) {
    $('html').removeClass(function(index, classes) {
        return classes.match(/\bchrome.*?\b/g).join(' ');
    }).addClass('ms-edge');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be using some thin like this

```
var str= window.navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase();
// This will return "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/55.0.2883.87 safari/537.36"
```

In the above string you need to check your conditions as below

```
if (str.includes("edge") == true) {
    $('html').removeClass(function(index, classes) {
        return classes.match(/\bchrome.*?\b/g).join(' ');
    }).addClass('ms-edge');
}
```

Screen shots of various test in the browser console.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aravind, I was looking for a whole (maybe better) different way though, perhaps even going to the lengths of modifying the head.js script

Comment: you want a different solution?

Comment: Your solution is good,  just wondering if there's another approach to this issue

Comment: the point is `window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge')` this will always return -1. so your condition never gets executed

Comment: Actually it does work, as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZViRlRF.png) (screenshot taken from "Edge" developer tools console)